# floating menu bar in containing div (js)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript menu bar that is positioned on my webpage, then when the browser bar reaches the top of the menu it locks into a fixed position and moves with the window. However, i need to contain the menu within a div, how can this be done?

This is my menu bar:

```
<script type="text/javascript"     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 200)
        {
            $("#floatbar").css({position:'fixed',left:'0',top:'0'});
        }
        else
        {
            $("#floatbar").css({position:'absolute',left:'0',top:'200px'});
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

and this is my html:

```
<div id="menu_runner">
    <div id="floatbar">
        <a href="#issue49">Issue 49</a><br />
        <a href="#issue48">Issue 48</a><br />
        <a href="#issue47">Issue 47</a><br />
        <a href="#issue46">Issue 46</a><br />
    </div>
</div>
```

and my css:

```
#menu_runner {
    width: 100px;
    height: 2000px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}
#floatbar {
    width: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
}
```

where the menu runner is the containing div of the menu, and the floatbar obviously contains the menu which runs the JavaScript.

However when I try this code, the menu sticks to the left and 200px from the top, and not within the menu_runner div. How can i make the floatbar be positioned in the menu_runner div and then scroll down with the JavaScript within the div as it should.

Here's a live demo of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/f4dhy/

Comment: Wait, what? Can you be a bit more precise about your question? I'm not really understanding what the problem is.

Comment: Hi blender, my problem is that I want my menu contained in the floatbar div, to be positioned on my page so that it runs along side my content. Its a two column layout which, the container div is central on the page, which means I cant just use absolute positioning, because where I position it on my screen, will be different (in correlation to the content) on another size screen.

So I need to position the menu within the 'menu_runner' div, which is positioned how I want it, and will display correctly on all screens. All i need is a way to contain the JS in that div. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one method:

## [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f4dhy/2/)

Javascript:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 200) {
    screenWidth = $(window).width();
    containerWidth = $("#menu_runner").outerWidth(true);
    pos = screenWidth - containerWidth;
    $("#floatbar").css({
        position: 'fixed',
        left: pos,
        top: '0'
    });
}
else {
    $("#floatbar").css({
        position: 'absolute',
        left: '0',
        top: '200px'
    });
}
});
```

The idea is get the screen's width, the menu container's width, and from that we get figure out how to position the left edge of the menu so that it lines up with the container.

In your css, add:

```
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

which fixes the slightly off positioned problem you'd see without it due to the default margin set by browsers.

You might see the menu kinda bounce into position when you scroll it to the top, which is unfortunate but hopefully not too much of a problem.

This doesn't work in IE6 because of the position:fixed being used. You'll have to search for a solution to that. I'm not too familiar with what the accepted workaround is (but a [quick](http://tagsoup.com/cookbook/css/fixed/) google [search](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/layouts/fixed.html) shows a few hacks that might work)

I'm curious though, any reason you want to do it this way? Why have the menu scroll with the screen and then stop at the top? Why not just fix it to one place on the screen from the start, something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/H66sh/)?

Comment: I'm very new when it comes to javascript, i'm having to use it through necessity to achieve the effect i'm after here. Should I adjust the code to include screen width and container width, or is the code you posted the finalised code?
I need to use this method as I have explained in my comment to 'blender' in the above post (hope that clarifies things in regards to that).

I have tried to implement your code, but it just shifts to the right, which must mean it is now contained in the menu_runner (which is was not before your help!) but now the menu runner is out of position? thanks for helping

Comment: The widths are automatically figured out using javascript, so the code should not need to be adjusted. Have you added anything else to the page, or are you saying something is wrong when you try just the [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f4dhy/2/)? I did move the menu_runner a little bit with the css added to the body, is that the issue? Removing that will get you the original position you had, but then your floatbar will be off a bit when you scroll it and you'll need to further tweak its position.

Comment: Also, without going into all the details, technically your floatbar is not contained within the menu_runner, because that isn't possible with elements that are positioned absolute or fixed. I just made it look like it is (but then you have to ask: do you really need that container? because something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/H66sh/1/) would work to keep your menu always in view). I'm sure there are other (better) ways of achieving the layout you want, and maybe someone else will be able to offer it.

Comment: Hi there zxt, I think I do need the menu_runner, however, if you say that the effect I am trying to accomplish is impossible then maybe it will be. [Here](http://www.tomfrostpersonaltrainer.co.uk/articles.html) is the site I am coding. as this is the page i need the effect on, I need the menu to be next to all the article content in the main body. do you think this would be possible? if not, your help so far has been excellent and I will vote your answer top, as at least its on the right hand side now! :)

Comment: Hi there zxt.

sorted this with [this](http://www.jtricks.com/javascript/navigation/floating/confined_demo.html) script. 

Thanks for all your help though, you helped me understand the js I was implementing a bit better! :)